# Calculate Logarithmic Trendline end-point values in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, trendline

I have an existing report in Microsoft Access.  The report displays the dynamic chart below:
[image: TrendLine]

I am trying to use a VBA reference to the Logarithmic Values of the chart (green line).  Specifically, I need to know the actual beginning point (approximately 0.85) and the end point (approximately 1.18).

Can this be done?

Comment: If Log Equation: y = (c * LN(x)) + b where c: =INDEX(LINEST(y,LN(x)),1) and b: =INDEX(LINEST(y,LN(x)),1,2)

Comment: The green line looks linear, is it not? If it is, you can use the linear line equation. `y=mx+b`